# Java Arithmetic calculate cylinder volume

Tags: java

I'm new to java and have being trying to solve this problem for a while now. Any chance someone could help me with part B. I'd really appreciate it!

> Create a single Java program called Question 4 to calculate the following:
>   A. The volume of a cylindrical tin of soup of diameter 7cm and height 10½cm
>   B. The area of a rectangular wrapper to cover the soup tin of part (A) 
>   C. The total surface area of cling film required to completely wrap the tin 
>   of soup from (A)
>
> Each section should be separated by a comment. Make sure that the program is
>   calculating the answer.

Edit: Sorry everyone, I've never actually used this site before so i feel pretty stupid now. Here's how far I've gotten:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    double height,dia, volume;
    // user input
    System.out.println("Calculate Volume of Cylinder");
    System.out.print("Enter height: ");
    height = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter diameter : ");
    dia = in.nextDouble();
    // Calculate volume
    volume = pi*dia/4*dia*height;
    // Display volume
    System.out.print("Volume = " + volume);
    System.out.println(" Cubic Units");
```

I know this code is sloppy but it gives me the right answer for part A. Its part B i cant understand. I'm not sure about how to connect the two.

```
        double len,width,sq;
    System.out.println("Calculate Area of Rectangle");
    System.out.print("Enter length: ");
    len = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter width: ");
    width = in.nextDouble();
    double area = len*width;
    System.out.print("Area = "+ area);
```

Comment: No...I will not do that. Let's see what you've done.

Comment: Please, show us your efforts.

Comment: No, SO is not a "code this for me" site. Take a stab at it, referring to the documentation and various Java tutorials, and if you get stuck somewhere, post a question about the specific thing you're stuck on, showing the code where you're stuck.

Comment: A=2πrh+2πr2 and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html is about all your going to get.

Answer (score 0):

You have to figure out how much wrapper you need, you already know the diameter and height of the soup can. Since D=2*r, and C=2*pi*r, the area of the rectangular wrapper you need is (2*pi*r)(21/2).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to ask for input for length and width. You already have everything you need. The width of the rectangle == the height of the cylinder. The length of the rectangle == the circumference of the top of the cylinder. You can work it out from there, I'm sure.